How to fully disable tabs in VS Code? (not simply hidden, only one editor per pane allowed)
In Visual Studio code it's possible to hide tabs, but the tabs are still present behind the scenes. If you use the 'Close Editor' action, the pane does not close. The 'Close Editor Group' solution is too fragile and prevents fully not thinking about it.
